# How to update Google Play Services without having a Google account?

Tags: updates, google-account, google-play-services

I have installed an app which apparently requires a newer version of Google Play Services. How can I upgrade these services to a newer version without having a Google account?

This is on Android 4.4.2.

Comment: go to settings > google play services app > tap build version > an update button should appear > tap that

Comment: That will only work with a Google account.

Comment: Btw. it's sad that the answer regarding Evozi and malware is not visible anymore. IMHO even bad answers should remain visible so it's clear which ideas have been suggested already.

Comment: @oliver Good, valid point. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to goto a 3rd party website that hosts Google apps and download the newest (for your device) version. The one I use is  http://gappsandroid.blogspot.com/ , you can download EVERY single Official Google app.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds very interesting! Follow-up question: do you know where this site gets the APKs? And how can we be sure they don't add any malware embedded to their files?  I'm somewhat suspicious about downloading programs from random internet pages :-)

Comment: I can research tomorrow for you, but I'm pretty sure everything is on the up and up. I've been using this site for awhile now and haven't had any issues at all. I'm really particular about this situation as well.

Comment: APKMirror.com from Android Police is a good one too. They get the APK's from the community but test them before posting. They should be pretty safe.

Comment: @oliver Well I didn't get any conclusive details on the website, but I've compared the the files to those released on the PlayStore and they are the same. I have also gotten some pre-released versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [OpenGApps](http://opengapps.org/).  I believe it is sanctioned by Google and allows you to easily select a version for your device architecture and Android version, customizing the package by which apps/services you want.

Once downloaded, you can flash the package via recovery.  It is also possible to extract the apps for a manual upgrade; see [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/159558/1465) for details.